# How do i manage multiple sections that change structure in a large react-hook-form form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, react-hook-form

I have a large form that is comprised of sections A, B, C. However, each section can be in one of two shapes: A1 or A2, B1 or B2, C1, or C2. Basically, a user is filling out some settings, and there is an "advanced" set of settings, and a "basic" set of settings. The user must fill out the form section based on which shape that section is set to. Type-wise, this is represented as the union `BasicSettings | AdvancedSettings` where `mode: 'advanced' | 'basic'` is the discriminator. I want to be able to submit the form as one large form, where each of these sections can be either in their advanced or in the basic state. How can I achieve this while maintaining that the user only needs to click submit in one place in order to submit all the sections?

My current approach is to treat the form as one large form, and then render each section separately by using the FormProvider and accessing the context. When the user switches from a basic to an advanced shape, or the other way around, I reset the defaults for that specific section via `resetField`. I could continue down this path but i've found it to be fairly verbose and error-prone, and i was hoping there would be a simpler way to leverage react-hook-form for this use case than manually managing the resetting of each sections defaults and values. I also considered treating each "advanced" and "basic" section as its own form so that when i switch rendering from one to the other i dont have to worry about resetting defaults. However, using multiple forms implied that each section would be submitted separately, instead of together as is required.

Answer (score 1):

You may use conditional rendering to switch between the basic and advanced states of each section, and then use the useForm hook from react-hook-form to manage the state and validation of the form as a whole. You can define the form schema and validation rules using the register and rules methods from the useForm hook, and then use the watch method to retrieve the current state of the form data.

To submit the form as one large form, you can define a single onSubmit function that retrieves the current state of the form data using the watch method, and then sends it to your backend API. This way, the user only needs to click the submit button once to submit all the sections of the form together.

You can also use the reset method from the useForm hook to reset the form to its default state when the user switches between the basic and advanced states of each section. This way, you don't have to manually manage the resetting of each section's defaults and values.

Overall, this approach should simplify your code and make it easier to manage the state and validation of the form.